# Google CSA and AMP integration

Tags: amp-html

I wonder how to implement Google Custom Search Ads (CSA) over AMP: https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/

Google CSA integration it's not available over amp-ad yet and amp-iframe does not fit well with this kind of advertising.

Any suggestions or ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you are correct, Google Custom Search Ads (CSA) is not yet supported in AMP pages.

You can try using [`amp-ad`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/amp-ad.html) as it support AdSense.

```
<amp-ad width=300 height=200
    type="adsense"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-8125901705757971"
    data-ad-slot="7783467241">
</amp-ad>
```

Sources:

- [sample](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-ad/)
- [github](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/google/adsense.md)

Comment: Adsense it's not a good replacement for CSA as they are completely different products. Do you know if there are any plans to adapt CSA to AMP? Is it possible to send a request to someone? Thanks!

Comment: @JavierM CSA is a standard. The link https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/ you cited literally talks about AdSense (see for example title "AdSense Custom Search Ads"). I guess you may need to include some more info and more preferably code about what you want to AMP-ify.

Comment: @JavierM https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-ad/?referrer=ampproject.org#supported-ad-networks